# Swift: Property 'self.tableView' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: swift

I have a class in my Swift code which designs `UICollectionViewCells`

```
class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 

    let tableView: UITableView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        designCell()
    }
}
```

I need to have a `UITableView` in the cell thus i added `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` classes,but this returns me following error

`Property 'self.tableView' not initialized at super.init call`
What may be the problem and how can i initialize tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either create and connect the outlet of `UITableView` or create it programmatically

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: yourFrame)
```

Comment: Thank you for thy answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the initialization rules all stored properties must be initialized before calling an `init` method of the super class. Declaring a property as implicit unwrapped optional does not initialize the property.

Declare `tableView` as non-optional and initialize it before the `super` call

```
class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView: UITableView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        designCell()
    }
}
```